# ROS installation on RPI <== Failed to process package 'urdf':

Tags: ros, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following these steps http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi for installing ROS Indigo on a RPI3. I keep getting this error below when I compile the package. I've applied the two patches that are recommended in the wiki and tried to verify all my dependencies but nothing helped. Please help.

`<== Finished processing package [176 of 188]: 'turtle_tf2'

==> Processing catkin package: 'urdf'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh'
==> cmake /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_model/urdf -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/hom                                                                                                                     e/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/urdf -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo -D                                                                                                                     CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isol                                                                                                                     ated/urdf'
-- Boost version: 1.55.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package):
By not providing "Findurdfdom.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "urdfdom", but
CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "urdfdom" with any
of the following names:

```
urdfdomConfig.cmake
urdfdom-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "urdfdom" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"urdfdom_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
"urdfdom" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
been installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/urdf/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log"                                                                                                                     .
<== Failed to process package 'urdf':
Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'cmake', '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot                                                                                                                     _model/urdf', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/urdf'                                                                                                                     , '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G',                                                                                                                      'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/urdf && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh cmak                                                                                                                     e /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/robot_model/urdf -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/pi/ros                                                                                                                     _catkin_ws/devel_isolated/urdf -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/indigo -DCMAKE_BU                                                                                                                     ILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238484/ros-installation-on-rpi--%3C==-failed-to-process-package-%27urdf%27:/) by [AloshkaD](https://answers.ros.org/users/27344/aloshkad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-06-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-30**:
Please format console copy/pastes using the *Preformatted text* button (the one with `101010` on it). That will make this much more legible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I checked the dependencies I realized that liburdfdom-dev failed to install and that's probably the issue. I'm trying to fix it and I will post the solution if that was indeed the issue.

---

Originally posted by [AloshkaD](https://answers.ros.org/users/27344/aloshkad/) with karma: 16 on 2016-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nate](https://answers.ros.org/users/27411/nate/) on 2016-07-07**:
I got the same failure.  Did you find a fix?

**Comment by [AloshkaD](https://answers.ros.org/users/27344/aloshkad/) on 2016-07-07**:
Yes I did.I downloaded the liburdfdom-dev and installed it on my system . I had to remove it twice and force install it because I kept getting an installation error.

**Comment by [Nate](https://answers.ros.org/users/27411/nate/) on 2016-07-07**:
Hi.  Thanks for your reply!  When I attempted to sudo apt-get install liburdfdom-dev I then ran into another dependency issue... it was complaining about not having the libconsole-bridge-dev dependency.  Did you run into this issue as well?  I really appreciate your help.

**Comment by [Nate](https://answers.ros.org/users/27411/nate/) on 2016-07-07**:
I ended up doing the same thing you did.  I had to remove both liburdfdom-dev and the console-bridge and rebuild both.  Thanks again for the pointer!

**Comment by [AloshkaD](https://answers.ros.org/users/27344/aloshkad/) on 2016-07-07**:
Glad that helped, I was stuck on this issue for 3 days.

**Comment by [prat33kg](https://answers.ros.org/users/33696/prat33kg/) on 2018-02-19**:
Hey guys. Can anyone tell me the command used to remove this dependency? Thanks in advance.